# Regex check return true for "

Tags: regex

I have `/^\w+( \w+)*$/`

It tests for one space between words, and no leading or trailing spaces.

However, it fails on an edge case where it is passed just the blank string `"`

I have tried:

```
/^\w"+( \w+)*$/ 
/^\w\"+( \w+)*$/
/^\w|"+( \w+)*$/
```

but then it fails my other tests.

Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add an alternation for the blank:

```
^$|^\w+( \w+)*$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/qteSfreg5qsOtw).

IMHO it's easy to read and understand.